# Python getopt get unlimited args

Tags: python

How can i get something like below command with `getopt`?

python script.py -u "url_a" "url_b" "url_c" -s

I am using below code but i cannot receive all of urls , it only return one of urls

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "u:s")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
python script.py -u "url_a url_b url_c" -s
```

and:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "u:s")
urls = opts[0][1].split()
```

Comment: I have another question , how can i set parameter as required parameter?
for example when script does not run with `-c` parameter, go to except?

Comment: Check that opts doesn't contain a ("-c","whatever") option.

Comment: How? i am new in python